# How to read a table from database at pyramid application startup?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a `pyramid` game server app that uses `sqlalchemy` to read/write to `postgres` database. I want to read a certain table(call it `games`) from the database at the time this app is created. This `games` data will be used by one of my `wsgi middleware`, that is hooked in the app, to send `statsd` metrics. To do this, I added a subscriber in the main function of my app like:

```
config.add_subscriber(init_mw_data, ApplicationCreated)
```

Now, I want to read the `games` table in the following function:

```
def init_mw_data(event):
    ...
    ...
```

Anybody know how I can read `games` table inside the function `init_mw_data` ?

Answer (score 0):

It based how you configured your application.
Default sqlalchemy template from `pyramid-cookiecutter-starter` have `dbsession_factory`.

So, you can do something like this:

```
def init_mw_data(event):
     registry = event.app.registry
     dbsession = registry['dbsession_factory']()
     dbsession.query(...)
     ...
```